# transformNode function for ie9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, xslt

I need to transform an xml doc into another xml doc using xslt in ie9 or above versions.

I am trying to transform an xml doc using xslt in ie9. When i used transformNode() function it is working fine in ie8(code:: resultDocument = XML.transformNode(XSL);) but in ie9 transformNode function is not defined showing error::**SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'transformNode'**

I found a solution for ie9 as given below

```
if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                console.log('inside hi');
                var xslt = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate");
                var xslDoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument");
                xslDoc.loadXML(xsltDoc.xml);
                console.log(xslt.styleSheet);
                xslt.stylesheet = xslDoc;
                var xslProc = xslt.createProcessor();
                xslProc.input = xmlDoc;
                xslProc.transform();
                return xslProc.output;
            }
```

but when i run this i get an error: **SCRIPT16389: The stylesheet does not contain a document element.  The stylesheet may be empty, or it may not be a well-formed XML document.**

I am new to javascript/jquery. Can anyone please help me in resolving this. If there is any other function either in javascript or jquery it would be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you get that `XML` document from?

Answer (score 1):

With earlier versions of IE the `responseXML` document used to be an MSXML DOM document and MSXML implements XSLT and `transformNode`. With newer IE versions the `responseXML` document gives you an IE DOM document and IE does not implement XSLT and `transformNode` for its DOM document/nodes. Nor does an IE DOM document have a property `xml` you are trying to use in `xslDoc.loadXML(xsltDoc.xml);`.

Try changing that part of the code to

```
if (typeof XMLSerializer !== 'undefined') {
  xslDoc.loadXML(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xsltDoc));
  // now use xslDoc here
}
```

A different option is to use `xslDoc.loadXML(xmlHttp.responseText);` if you still have access to the XMLHttpRequest. There is also an option to ensure you get an MSXML responseXML, see `try { xhr.responseType = 'msxml-document'; } catch(e){}` line in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/07/19/xmlhttprequest-responsexml-in-ie10-release-preview.aspx.

Your whole approach to object checking in your code is wrong, check for the object or property or method you want to use (e.g. `if (typeof XSLTProcessor !== 'undefined') { // now use XSLTProcessor here }`), not for completely different object like `document.implementation`.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the `SCRIPT16389: The stylesheet does not contain a document element. The stylesheet may be empty, or it may not be a well-formed XML document` error in IE9/10/11.  I've found the following fixes it:

your code:

```
if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    console.log('inside hi');
    var xslt = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate");
    var xslDoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument");

    xslDoc.loadXML(xsltDoc.xml);

    console.log(xslt.styleSheet);
    xslt.stylesheet = xslDoc;
    var xslProc = xslt.createProcessor();
    xslProc.input = xmlDoc;
    xslProc.transform();
    return xslProc.output;
 }
```

working code:

```
if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    console.log('inside hi');
    var xslt = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate");
    var xslDoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument");

    xslDoc.load(xsltDoc);

    console.log(xslt.styleSheet);
    xslt.stylesheet = xslDoc;
    var xslProc = xslt.createProcessor();
    xslProc.input = xmlDoc;
    xslProc.transform();
    return xslProc.output;
 }
```

The change being line 6 - replace 'loadXML' with 'load' and 'xsltDoc.xml' with just 'xsltDoc'.  Let me know how it goes!